# Append unique rows only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having difficulties building a script which would only append rows which are not currently present on the sheet.

I have a master sheet, to which I'm importing `csvData`. At this moment, I have 1 script for importing csv data and another to clear the sheet from possible duplicates after the import. Although this works, duplicate removal script uses `.clearContent` and is forced to clear the sheet entirely before returning a list of unique rows. Because the spreadsheet is being used externally (via Appsheet), it creates a risk of unrecorded/corrupted data if any of the users tries to add anything to the sheet while the script is being executed.

Because of this, I am trying to build another script, which would import `csvData` to an empty array, and then compare it with the array extracted from the master sheet. Via comparison, the script would only append rows which are not yet present on the master sheet.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find examples of duplicate removal without sheet's content clearing. I had another idea for counting repetitions and only selecting the ones which had none, but I wasn't able to make a working script/find an example for that either.

Below is my original script, which includes both importing and duplicate removal using `.clearContent`:

```
function importEMS() {
  var fSource=DriveApp.getFolderById('folder id removed'); 
  var fi=fSource.getFilesByName('EMS.csv'); 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet id removed');

  //CONVERT CSV FILE TO A TABLE
  if (fi.hasNext()) { 
    var file=fi.next();
    var csv=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData=CSVToArray(csv);
    var timestamp = new Date();
    var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Main');
    for (var i=1;i<csvData.length-1;i++) {
      csvData[i][8] = timestamp;
    }

   //APPEND NEW ROWS

    for (var i=1;i<csvData.length;i++) {
      tsh.appendRow(csvData[i]);
    }
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){

      if(row.slice(0,7).join().toLowerCase() == newData[j].slice(0,7).join().toLowerCase()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  // Clear the existing info and update with newData.
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to append new rows only instead of the entire `csvData` to the master sheet?

Thanks for the help in advance!

UPD: Added a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m_FAl0a0iyTpA426hnCwV1TAVSF32aHjpIqpFMOTLus) to a data sample. The real main sheet contains 20 columns, but I removed them from the sample, the column order is identical. CSV import sheet is the type of data that I import. On that sheet, I highlighted with green which rows I'm trying to append to the main sheet.

UPD2: Provided solution by Oleg Valter functions, but only if I replace `.getValues()` by `.getDisplayValues()`, which converts all present types of data into strings, which is also the format in which .csv data is imported.

Comment: Can you share a sample copy of your data file and your master sheet.

Comment: Is there more than one `EMS.csv` file? Why do you append a time stamp to all the rows except the first and the last?

Comment: As you've desribed the problem, it seems to me that you might want to rethink the problem. The `CSVToArray` returns a 2-dimensional array, right? So does the `getValues()`. If you used the `filter()` Array method, you could leave only those that aren't equal to any returned by `getValues()` and just append the result. 
May I also ask if you need to `toLowerCase()` to compare values?

Comment: @Cooper, attached a sample! I keep track of the times when the data was appended to the main sheet. The first row is skipped as it contains column headers. The actual last row of the CSV file also gets a timestamp, but I had to add `.length-1` to an array, as otherwise the script wouldn't function.

Comment: @OlegValter, I use `.toLowerCase()` to avoid duplicates, as some sells are alphanumeric or plain text. I understand the logic of your solution, but I can't really transform it code-wise. Do you maybe have an example of how `filter()` could be used?

Comment: Does you csv file already contain a timestamp?

Comment: @EgorP - thanks for clarification! Yep, I've attached a sample algorithm as a code snippet in an answer below (it's probably not the best in terms of complexity - I can count at least O(n<sup>3</sup>), but should do the job). It is generic so you can expand it to what suits you best

Comment: @Cooper, no, it has only 8 columns, the timestamp is added after it has been imported to gSheets

Comment: @OlegValter thanks! I will take a look at it tomorrow at work and will see if it works!

Comment: NP! Please, let me know if the solution will work for you, should fit your use case just fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Get CSV values as an Array of Arrays (let's assume that's what `CSVToArray()` does).
2. Get current values as an Array of Arrays via `getDataRange().getValues()`.
3. Filter out duplicate values like this (assuming that every pair of rows has *the same length* - otherwise the algorithm becomes more complex, but judging from your code, you check first 8 values only):

```js
//source = [[...], ... , [...]];
//target = [[...], ... , [...]];

/**
 * Checks if at least one element
 * is positioned differently
 * @param {*[]} a
 * @param {*[][]} b
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
var unique = function (a,b) {
  return b.every(function(bRow){
    return a.some(function(A,aIdx){
      return A !== bRow[aIdx];
    });
  });
};

/**
 * Leaves only values not present in source
 * @param {*[][]} source
 * @param {*[][]} target
 * @returns {*[][]}
 */
var filterUnique = function (source,target) {
  return target.filter(function (row) {
    return unique(row,source);
  });
};

var S1 = [[1,2,3],['A','D','C'],[5],[7]];
var T1 = [[1,2,3],['A','B','C'],[6]];

var S2 = [[1.00,'Vehicle 1',1.00,'Ready','12-5-2020', 1, 'Event A', 'Location A']];
var T2 = [S2[0],[2.00,'V2',1.00,'Ready','12-5-2020', 1, 'Event A', 'Location A']];

var check1 = filterUnique(S1,T1);
var check2 = filterUnique(S2,T2);

console.log(check1,check2);
```

**Notes**

1. You would need to swap the check with timestamping and only timestamp after leaving only unique rows, otherwise there is a risk of appending the row because its timestamp is the only diff.

**References**

1. `every()` [method ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on MDN
2. `some()` [method ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on MDN
3. `filter()` [method ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on MDN

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I can't get it to work correctly. I used `data` as a source, `csvData` as a target and `newData` as a destination. When I run `filterUnique` function, it returns the entire `csvData` range to the `newData`. Do you have an idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Nevermind, that was my mistake! I had data formatting enabled on gSheet, so it wasn't reading the date right. I set it all to plain text and now it works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @EgorP! Glad to hear that the solution worked for you! Btw, you can add a guard for objects to  `A !== bRow[aIdx]` to avoid the need for stringifying (e.g. by checking `valueOf()` in case you only need dates) values. The joys of dealing with `{} !== {}` :)

Comment: I might need some additional help with your solution. I seem to be getting the problem with date reading. The `csvData` always has the date set to 4-2-2020 format, whereas `data` obtained from the sheet gets Tue Feb 04 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2020. I tried resetting formatting on gSheet, but it resets every time on a newly appended data. Do you have an idea how this can be avoided?

Comment: haha sorry, I started typing my previous comment before your comment got submitted. Would the guard thing help me to prevent the issue I described?

Comment: Comment mishaps happen all the time) As for your question - guard won't help you here, since `4-2-2020`, when passed to `new Date()` represents *Thu Apr 02 2020* (expected, since the format should be either ISO (YYYY-MM-DD) or UTC, you string is read as MM-DD-YYYY). But there are a couple of things you can do:
1. use [`setNumberFormats(numberFormats)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object)) when appending new rows

Comment: 2.This is a kind of an extension of the previous comment: if you can, change the data from CSV to standard format (if you know exactly which column it is always in, it can be done during comparison by value index) and then add the abovementioned guard like `bRow[aIdx] instanceof Date ? bRow[aIdx].valueOf() !== new Date(A).valueOf() : A !== bRow[aIdx]`

Comment: My apologies, I did not explain it correctly. Within the `csvData`, the 4th column containing dates is actually not recognized as a date, so it reads 4-2-2020 as a number, which then creates a conflict when it tries to compare it to the actual date from the main sheet reading as _Tue Fed 04 00:00:00 GMT +01:00 2020_.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make sure that the 4th column of `csvData` is always recognized as a date?

Comment: @EgorP - yeah, you can, see my comment above with the guard - the only thing is that 4-2-2020 will be interpreted as `Thu Apr 02 2020` instead of Feb, 4th 2020, so you would need to convert to 2020-02-04 first

Comment: Hi Oleg! Sorry to keep bugging you, but I'm afraid your suggestion hasn't worked. I did successfully convert the dates to the same format, but it still wouldn't function. Then I figured, that numbers in the `csvData`were actually seen as strings, whereas on the sheet they were recognized as numbers. I then converted all strings with digits into numbers, but the script would still not see any difference between existing and new rows. If I check the logger, rows from `csvData` and `data` look absolutely identical. Do you know what might be the problem here?

Comment: Hi @EgorP, no worries - it's hard to tell blindly - could you please make an update to your question so as it shows how the code is integrated - should be easier to tell then

Comment: Updated my main post, added my current code and a small explanation

Comment: Hi @EgorP - thank you for updating the post (though current edit no longer contains the updated code). If `getDisplayValues()` works - great! You could inspect each value via `typeof` to make sure what's wrong with actual values (or change the check from strict comparison to `!=` - it is likely that the values compared are of diff types)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @EgorP - NP, glad to help!